# WebAudioWorklet in webassembly Shared Array Buffer not defined

Tags: webassembly, web-audio-api, emscripten, sharedarraybuffer, audio-worklet

I ma trying to understand how to compile an Audio Worklet in webassembly using the Wasm Audio Worklets API of the emscripten.

Using the code listed in the tutorial on the API reference [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/wasm_audio_worklets.html) and compiling the code using:

```
em++ audioworklet.cpp -sAUDIO_WORKLET=1 -sWASM_WORKERS=1 -o worklet.html
```

I get an error in the browser (both Firefox and Chrome):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined
```

I also tried to compile some of the webaudio test code on the [emscripten repository](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/tree/main/test/webaudio) for example `audioworklet.c` using `emcc` instead of `em++` but I always get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

you can find a copy of the glue code (both `js` and `html`) automatically generated from the compilation instruction provided above: https://gist.github.com/ddgg-el/e6819f773abbfc75385c7fa15d79b692.

The error is thrown by line 459 of the `worklet.js`

thank you!

Comment: Can you share your HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: @Jonas I just added a link to the files. Thank you for reaching out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a good chance that you don't set the required headers which are mandatory these days to enable `SharedArrayBuffer` support.

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
```

As far as I can tell you even need to set those headers when running your website on localhost.

You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer#security_requirements) or [web.dev](https://web.dev/coop-coep/).

Comment: Yes! that was it! Than you!

Comment: In my specific case, I use to work with VSCode, changing the "Live Server" extension in favor of "Live Preview" did the trick. Thanks to this extension I could add:

`"livePreview.httpHeaders": { "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp", "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin","Accept-Ranges": "bytes"}`
to my `settings.json` and everything worked as expected

Comment: @ddgg This might work locally, but once your code runs from an online web server (other than localhost), that server needs to add these headers. See https://replayer.app/en/documentation/providing-content-with-replayer#from-your-own-web-server (Replace "Replayer" with your own solution)